# Is it possible to build applications that specify dependencies using manifests using Visual Studio 6.0 (VC98 compiler)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I'm trying to port a win32 application that is currently built using the VC98 compiler on command line (**not** the IDE).

I wish to enable Visual Styles for this application so that the application gets the new themed controls that came with Windows XP.

The way to go I've learnt for this is to use a manifest and specify version 6 of ComCtl32.dll.

Is it possible to do this in my application **without** upgrading the compiler?

In other words, can we use Visual Studio 6.0 (command line build interface) to specify a manifest file for an application?

Comment: Not sure about whether you can do it via a command line option, but you can probably embed the manifest in a resource file, as explained on [both](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for enabling visual styles.

Comment: @andlabs it can be done from the command line

Answer (score 2):

A manifest is just a resource. Compile the resource and link it to your executable just like any other resource.

Indeed you don't need to resort to the command line to do this. You are able to link dialog resources, icon resources and so on from the IDE. You can do the same with a manifest resource.

Various options for embedding the resource are described here: 
[How to embed a manifest in an assembly: let me count the ways...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cheller/archive/2006/08/24/how-to-embed-a-manifest-in-an-assembly-let-me-count-the-ways.aspx)

Comment: This was my first thought upon reading the question. My only concern would be that the old VC6 toolchain lacks support for embedding manifests. For example, the version of rc.exe wouldn't even know what a manifest is. You could probably embed the manifest as a binary blob, but it wouldn't be quite as easy as the blog post describes. Alternatively, you can use a newer version of mt.exe that does support manifests, and run it as a post-build event.

Comment: @Cody It's just a text file. All versions of rc can compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me on VS6:

Simply put this into your .rc file:

```
1                       RT_MANIFEST             "manifest.xml"
```

or if `RT_MANIFEST` is not defined:

```
1                       24             "manifest.xml"
```

Where `manifest.xml` is the manifest file which is this in my case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly
   xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
   manifestVersion="1.0">
   <assemblyIdentity
     processorArchitecture="x86"
     version="1.0.0.0"
     type="win32"
     name="somename.exe"/>

  <description>Some description</description>

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <dependency> 
    <dependentAssembly> 
      <assemblyIdentity 
        type="win32" 
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
        version="6.0.0.0" 
        processorArchitecture="X86" 
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" 
        language="*" 
      /> 
    </dependentAssembly> 
  </dependency> 

</assembly>
```

The important part for comctrl32 6.0 is the `<dependency>` part. The `<trustinfo>` part is also more or less required nowadays.